# Efficient way to reference one table from another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following two data frames:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'name': np.repeat(['Brandon', 'Erica'], [3, 4]),
                    'date': ['2019-01', '2019-02', '2019-03', '2018-01', '2018-02', '2018-03', '2018-04'],
                    'value': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'name': np.repeat(['Brandon', 'Erica'], [2, 2]),
                    'date': ['2019-02', '2019-03', '2018-01', '2018-04']})

print(df1)
#      name     date  value
#0  Brandon  2019-01      1
#1  Brandon  2019-02      2
#2  Brandon  2019-03      3
#3    Erica  2018-01      4
#4    Erica  2018-02      5
#5    Erica  2018-03      6
#6    Erica  2018-04      7


print(df2)
#      name     date
#0  Brandon  2019-02
#1  Brandon  2019-03
#2    Erica  2018-01
#3    Erica  2018-04
```

The goal is to add a new field to `df2` that sums the previous two rows of `df1` for the `name` and `date` fields from `df2`. If there are not two rows with the same name in `df1` prior to the `name`, `date` combination from `df2`, then the new field will be `NaN`.

Below is the code that I wrote to accomplish this, but I am interested in something more efficient than the for loop below. Thanks in advance.

```
value_sums = []
for i in range(len(df2)):
    f = df1.index[(df1['name'] == df2.iloc[i]['name']) & (df1['date'] == df2.iloc[i]['date'])].tolist()[0]
    if df1.iloc[f]['name'] != df1.iloc[(f-2)]['name']:
        value_sums.append(np.NaN)
    else:
        g = df1.iloc[(f-2):f]['value'].sum()
        value_sums.append(g)

df2['value_sums'] = value_sums

print(df2)
#      name     date  value_sums
#0  Brandon  2019-02         NaN
#1  Brandon  2019-03         3.0
#2    Erica  2018-01         NaN
#3    Erica  2018-04        11.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following would do what you're describing. It makes the assumption that the dates are sorted in ascending order within each `name` group, like in your example. You could enforce this with a sort, if it's not the case. As it avoids an explicit loop through the rows, it should be much faster at scale.

First, your initial setup:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'name': np.repeat(['Brandon', 'Erica'], [3, 4]),
                    'date': ['2019-01', '2019-02', '2019-03', '2018-01', '2018-02', '2018-03', '2018-04'],
                    'value': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'name': np.repeat(['Brandon', 'Erica'], [2, 2]),
                    'date': ['2019-02', '2019-03', '2018-01', '2018-04']})

print(df1)
#      name     date  value
#0  Brandon  2019-01      1
#1  Brandon  2019-02      2
#2  Brandon  2019-03      3
#3    Erica  2018-01      4
#4    Erica  2018-02      5
#5    Erica  2018-03      6
#6    Erica  2018-04      7


print(df2)
#      name     date
#0  Brandon  2019-02
#1  Brandon  2019-03
#2    Erica  2018-01
#3    Erica  2018-04
```

Next, let's implement your logic:

```py
df1['value_sum'] = df1.groupby(['name']).shift(1).rolling(2).value.sum()
df1
name    date    value   value_sum
0   Brandon 2019-01 1   NaN
1   Brandon 2019-02 2   NaN
2   Brandon 2019-03 3   3.0
3   Erica   2018-01 4   NaN
4   Erica   2018-02 5   NaN
5   Erica   2018-03 6   9.0
6   Erica   2018-04 7   11.0
```

We grouped by name, shifted by one, and then took a rolling sum with window size two. The shift and rolling window of size two make sure we're looking "backward two" for the sum.

Finally, we merge the dataframes:

```py
df2.merge(df1[['name', 'date', 'value_sum']], how='left', on=['name', 'date'])
name    date    value_sum
0   Brandon 2019-02 NaN
1   Brandon 2019-03 3.0
2   Erica   2018-01 NaN
3   Erica   2018-04 11.0
```